# Will local information improve signups for a landing page?

Tags: landing-page

**The story so far:**

Client has landing pages that currently exist and are performing poorly (not enough users are filling out a contact form). Their product / service is a big emotional & financial commitment, so I'm suggesting a long-form landing page. My team is putting together a list of recommendations to revise the pages in hopes of having them perform better.

The one question that has come up which I am not sure about is does local information have a big impact on a conversion? For example, would placing a picture of the team from the clinic in your area be a benefit? Obviously we could just do it anyways because why not, or we could just make multiple iterations and test on all of them, but I'm wondering what people's thoughts are on here.

Comment: What is the purpose/goal of your landing pages, and why do the existing landing pages underperform relative to that goal?  It's hard to assess whether local information will be helpful without understanding what you are trying to achieve.  Are you selling a product, asking for signups, trying to get click-throughs, trying to target a demographic, etc

Comment: I should have clarified that, sorry. We aren't entirely sure why the landing pages are underperforming, but lack of content when there is a bigger price tag = more objections. The content team needs to take the time to counter each possible objection on the landing page. The goal is to have a form submitted. The biggest problem is that we are **not** being given credit from the client for click throughs to their site (when users feel they need to learn more before committing) which is where I feel like long form landing pages can address the problem again.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. Sorry for being obtuse here but I still don't understand what your landing page is and what you are trying to get out of it. You reference clinics, a form and a price tag but that provides very little information on what the page actually is. Can you clarify?

Comment: No problem. I wasn't sure how much information I could give out, but I got more context on it and can share one of the pages. Here it is: http://landing.cranialtech.com/causes/. We have proposed rewriting content with more content on the page to answer concerns directly on the landing page instead of the user feeling the need to go to their site to learn more before converting (where we don't get credit). Hope that clears it up a bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### More information does not necessary drive conversion

In fact, too much information can decrease conversion because users feel overwhelmed.

*"We should provide more information"* is a common reaction to an underperforming landing page.

However, the volume of information is rarely the actual cause of underperformance.  The more common root causes are:

- Failure to understand the core and **precise** objective of the page.  Are you trying to maximize signups irrespective of quality?  Educate users about a product?  Ensure that only serious users sign up?  Target a demographic?
- Failure to tailor a **proper behavioral workflow** for the page.  It doesn't matter how much information you provide if the page is laid out so that the user cannot perceive an easy visual flow through the page.
- Failure to design a proper **call to action**.  You may have high quality information, but failing to create a clear call to action and a clear benefit to the user for taking that action will reduce conversions.
- Failure to provide the **right information**.  For example, you may believe the user needs to understand the *features* of a product, but really the user needs to understand *why the product matters* to begin with.

I would suggest sitting down and writing precisely what objectives the landing page has and what order of priority to give to those objectives.  Then do research on how to design a successful landing page.

---

Specific site-reviews are beyond the scope of UX StackExchange, so I will not comment specifically for your landing page except to say that I think you are thinking too much about "what information the user needs" rather than "how to convince the user to ask for a contact".

Comment: glad it was helpful, good luck!!!